# Why is readline/readline.h the same as readline/history.h on Mac OSX?

Tags: c, readline

When diffing those two header files (at least on OSX 10.8), they seem to be the same:

```
prompt:~ conradk$ diff /usr/include/readline/readline.h /usr/include/readline/history.h
prompt:~ conradk$
```

Why are both needed? If this is for historical reason (BC or something), could you please provide some examples or dates for when which was used?

The reason I'm asking is because I've seen `.c` files including both.

Comment: Not sure what OSX does, but you can find the source [here](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/readline.git/tree/).  And those are *pretty* different.

Comment: Btw `history` referrs to `readline`'s "history" feature, not to the history of `readline`'s development.